# Compose rigid transformation

Tags: python, torch

Implement the multiplication of two rigid matrices, 4x4 matrices A, whose last rows are [0, 0, 0, 1]:

RT23 -> A23=[R23, T23; 0, 0, 0, 1]

RT12 -> A12=[R12, T12; 0, 0, 0, 1]

Then, if you do the matrix block-multiplication on the 4x4 matrices (A13 = A23 * A12), you'll quickly find out that:

R13 = R23 * R12

T13 = R23 * T12 + T23

How to implement it in python, for example: torch.bmm(A12, A23) or torch.bmm(A23, A12), which one is correct?

I try to use python to implement it, for example: torch.bmm(A12, A23) or torch.bmm(A23, A12), the multiplication results are different in different orders.

Comment: You need to show us what you've done and what doesn't work.  We aren't going to write the code for you.  The documentation describes what the input sizes need to be:  https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.bmm.html

Answer (score 0):

As you didn''t share the source code you tried. It was a bit difficult to generate code as per your requirement. However I managed to come with a solution

```
import numpy as np

A23 = np.array([[R23, T23], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
A12 = np.array([[R12, T12], [0, 0, 0, 1]])
A13 = np.dot(A23, A12)
R13 = A13[:3, :3]
T13 = A13[:3, 3]
```

you mentioned that the correct formulas are R13 = R23 * R12 and T13 = R23 * T12 + T23. So you have to  follow this order:

```
R13 = np.dot(R23, R12)
T13 = np.dot(R23, T12) + T23
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If matrix is tensor type, do I directly replace np.dot with torch.bmm?